# ngClass in Angular 2 not rendering in table

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2-template, ng-class

I currently have a `<table>` in my template and need to apply styling in different parts (row, cell), I'm reading from a css file.  Everything was working fine when I only used the file style for styling the `<td>` elements, now I wanted to incorporate a class to style my table and things are not rendering, can someone take a look?  Thank you!

Now (not working for `<table>` and `<tr>`):

```
    <div>

<table [ngClass] = "'component'"> <!-- width ="100px;"-->
<tr [ngClass] = "'row'">  <!-- width ="100px;" height = "6px;"-->

<td [ngClass] = "{'weak' : weak, 'neutral' : !weak}"></td>
<td [ngClass] = "{'moderate' : moderate,'neutral' : !moderate  }" ></td>
<td [ngClass] = "{'strong' : strong, 'neutral' : !strong }" ></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

When I use this it works:

```
 <table width ="100px;">
    <tr width ="100px;" height = "6px>
```

Update (adding scss):

```
.component{

    width : "6.250em";
    position: relative
}
.row{
     width : "6.250em";
     height : ".375em"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed it to,

```
<table [ngClass] = "{'component':true}"> <!-- width ="100px;"-->
      <tr [ngClass] = "{'row':true}">  <!-- width ="100px;" height = "6px;"-->

        ...
      </tr>

</table>
```

OR

```
<table [class.component] = "true"> <!-- width ="100px;"-->
      <tr  [class.row] = "true">  <!-- width ="100px;" height = "6px;"-->

        ...
      </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, however it still didn't show the styling :(

Comment: where do you write style? in component or  global style sheet?

Comment: In a global style sheet (scss).

Comment: can you reproudce in plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/E31aE03iTXNZY0AEoyfU?p=preview its working as expected.

Comment: hey micronyks, this might be a stupid question, but the when I run the Plunker it juts says "loading".  I see the template that generates the <div> however other than loading I don't see anything

Comment: I had tried in IE :-D, switched to Chrome and I'm able to play with the Plunker, thank you.    Ok I pasted my css and is not the same, I'm still confused, let me add my scss to my question, maybe there is the issue

Comment: Oh I see. check n implement.